# Python Package removed by typing "pip uninstall package_name" in terminal, still shows up in the list output of "pip list"

Tags: python, pip, conda, folium

Is this normal? How do I make sure that the package (named folium) is completely removed from my computer?

I see a folder called "package_name.dist-info" under Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

I also have conda installed on my computer so when I do $conda list, the package shows in that output list also.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I'm aware, that is not normal. It looks like the folium package is in the site-packages for anaconda.  Perhaps your pip is not also the anaconda pip? What does `which pip` say? Perhaps try to uninstall using the anaconda pip directly via `/Users/my_name/anaconda/bin/pip uninstall folium`.

If that doesn't work, you can remove the "package_name.dist-info" folder you found and it should stop showing up in your `pip list` and `conda list`. You probably also want to check if the actual folium package is in the site-packages and remove that too.